# How to add icon in button html?

Tags: html

hi i need to add play icon in my button before watch demo button like in this images and gap between contact us and watch demo button. The icon and index.html both are in same folder thank you.
[image]

here is my result

[image]

```html
<div class="line">
                      <div class="s-10 m-10 l-3 center">
                        <a class="button button-white-stroke s-6" style="background-color:red;" href="/">+CONTACT US</a>
                        
                        <a class="button button-white-stroke s-6" style="background-color:black;" href="/">WATCH DEMO</a>
                        
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you should also post your CSS as well. Especially the button-white-stroke class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use font-awesome.
Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_video.asp) for more info.

For instance, your code would be as follows:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="line">
   <div class="s-10 m-10 l-3 center">
   <a class="button button-white-stroke s-6" style="background-color:red;"  href="/">+CONTACT US</a>
 <a class="button button-white-stroke s-6" style="margin-right:20px;background-color:black;" href="/"> <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>WATCH DEMO</a>                        
     </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Added  `<i class="fa fa-youtube-play">`

Comment: it display only a circle no play icon

Comment: and how i increase the gap between both button they are so close to each other

Comment: You should this <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> also in your html

Comment: For the gap increase, you can give some margin to the button.

Comment: ok but it wont add icon in watch button it only display whole white circle just

Comment: I am adding the full code in myanswer above.Please check that.

Comment: I have updated, For more styling, you should give the CSS you are using

Comment: image is added thank you but button is up and down now

Comment: For that you should add some margin and padding depending on how you are displaying. Also, Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. Thanks